# How do I prove $\frac{b_1}{d_1} < \frac{b_2} {d_2}$ implies $\frac{с_1 + b_1}{c_2 + d_1} < \frac{с_1 + b_2}{c_2 + d_2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

How do I prove $\frac{b_1}{d_1} < \frac{b_2} {d_2}$ implies $\frac{с_1 + b_1}{c_2 + d_1} < \frac{с_1 + b_2}{c_2 + d_2} (c_1, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb {R}; c_2, d_1, d_2 > 0)?$

Comment: This is wrong. Try $b_1=1, d_1=100, b_2=11, d_2=1000, c_1=c_2=1$.

Comment: are you sure of this?

Answer (score 1):

This statement is not true.
Let$$b_1=0, d_1=1, b_2=1, d_2=4, c_1=1,c_2=1.
$$
And here, $$\frac{0}{1} <\frac{1}{4}$$
But $$\frac{1}{2} > \frac{2}{5}$$
$$ $$

Comment: J. Doe, do this answer looks acceptable to you?